# Programmatically press the "select all" button in WFS capabilities of QGIS project properties with Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, wfs, pyqgis-3

I would like to ask if someone knows a way to press the "select all" button in Project>Properties>QGIS Server>WFS capabilities using python, or if is there a specific command to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```py
vectorLayers = [layer.id() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer)]
QgsProject.instance().writeEntry( "WFSLayers" , "/", vectorLayers);
QgsProject.instance().write()
```

Adapted from my previous answer [Publishing a layer as WFS with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362890/publishing-a-layer-as-wfs-with-pyqgis)

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot!