# QGIS Server OGC Features API fails on PostgreSQL layers

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-server, ogc-api

I'm attempting to use QGIS Server 3.18.1 to serve feature data via the new "WFS3" OGC Features API. I successfully installed the server by following [the manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-debian-based-systems) and using the referenced training data (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Training-Data/archive/v2.0.zip, world.qgs project, naturalearth.sqlite dataset) I can successfully interact with data at `http://localhost:8000/qgisserver/wfs3/collections?`

However I have not been able to access PostgreSQL layers through the Features API and from the logs it's not clear why. The layers simply aren't returned by the /collections endpoint. The same layers are available through QGIS Server's WMS interface, so I know that they are configured correctly in the project file and that the server has access to the database.

The only clue in the log is here:

```
INFO Server[94]: Using configuration file path from environment: /home/qgis/projects/pg-manual.qgs
WARNING PostGIS[94]: NOTICE: row number 0 is out of range 0..-1
```

Is there some technical reason why QGIS Server's OGC Features API implementation is currently unable to serve layers from PostgreSQL, even though they are available through WMS? If not, how can I further debug the issue here?

Comment: Do you use a view? Are you sure, you have a primary key? Question related to https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32523 mentioning the same error on Desktop QGIS Only a clue.

Comment: PS: Forgot to say I got a working "WFS3" OGC Features API with a layer based on PostGIS. Nearly sure, you already done it but did you also tick the WFS part in QGIS Server tab when opening the project on the QGIS Desktop?

Comment: @ThomasG77 thanks a bunch - the WFS publish checkbox was the issue. I'm actually generating the project file in pyqgis so it wasn't quite as simple as checking the box, but I found guidance on including the WFS publish step in pyqgis here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/362933/2788. If you can add your suggestion as an answer I will mark it accepted

Comment: I was the guy who also answered the related question you mentioned ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tick the WFS layer checkbox in "Published" column when you go to "Project" > "Properties" then in tab "QGIS Server" like illustrated for "airports2" layer.

[image: QGIS Server WFS configuration]